# Python 3.7 and Dataflow - SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to use the google cloud api to write my Dataflow jobs.

As I understand it, I can't use `pip install google-cloud-dataflow` since Apache Beam wont' work on Python 3, so I've been using `googleapiclient.discovery`. However, when I issue the `build()` command, it bombs out citing the error:

`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)`

Background notes:

- I'm sitting behind a Corporate Proxy, with HTTP(S)_PROXY set at the environment level
- I also have CA_BUNDLE and REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE set to my custom certs
- I've installed `certifi`, but no love
- I've attempted to run `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ 
  Certificates.command` but couldn't find the .command in my virtualenv. Also, would prefer not to go down this path as it will make my Prod deployment a nightmare

Here's my code:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
```

Result:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dataflow_creds.py", line 6, in 
    dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 222, in build
    requested_url, discovery_http, cache_discovery, cache)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 269, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1924, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1595, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1501, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/unit-test-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1291, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: got it working by exporting all Certs to a common file, then appending to the Cert file in the path as specified by Certifi

steps:

1. In Firefox > Preferences > View Certificates > Your Certificates, export all the required ones.
2. Concatenate all of the above .crt files into one big bundle.
3. In bash, run python -m requests.certs to get the certs file python is using.
4. Append the bundled certs from step 2 above to the file from step 3.
5. Done